# How to invoke ReactJS Component's method?

Tags: reactjs

New to ReactJS. Not sure If I am understanding it correctly.
I defined a table extends React.Component with methods like AddColumn. I created the table using React.createElement. How can I use the method I defined within table?

```
var element = React.createElement(CustomTable, {
  vscode:vscode,
  tableName:"test"
});

element.AddColumn("string", "haha", function(i, j){

});
```

I tried the code above and its not working as expected...

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to React, you should go start with Create React App. It's a boilerplate helps building React project. There are something you need to learn to build React project like Webpack, babel and so on but with CRA, you can start your first React project without building a development set up

Here is the site link
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/